# Value becomes empty when selecting button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my html code is like this :

```
<div class="span3">
            <div>DEBIT/CREDIT</div>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="investadjust-debitcredit-button">
                <button name="debitCredit" type="button" id="credit-button" class="btn active" value="CREDIT" >CREDIT</button>
                <button name="debitCredit" type="button" id="debi-button" class="btn" value="DEBIT" >DEBIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript code to get data:

```
 $("#investadjust-debitcredit-button>.active").val()
```

when i load the page itself the values  is empty like `value` because of this i am unable to get the value of selected button.

how to resolve this.

Comment: But where is the JavaScript that handles the button "selection"? The problem should be in there.

Comment: Show your JavaScript code.

Comment: javascript code is fine, but the value of the buttons become empty when the pages loads. this is what is the problem. any way updated the question with javascript code i use to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, i dont think switching between Button or Input elements will help. jQuery is entirely independent of that

well, you have not mentioned your javascript, but you can use following code to get Selected button value: -

```
$(".active", $(".btn-group")).val()
```

Try alerting the above sentence and you ll get wat u r looking for

Comment: this won't help as the value becomes empty when we load the page

Comment: then perhaps you should post you jQuery code, coz i tried my code in jsFiddle and its giving me result

Comment: The poster did not show any code so I can't assume they were using jQuery.

Comment: Perhaps @Anto, you should know, your jQuery is INCORRECT and it will always return undefined. It doesnt mean, value of button gets null on page load.

Just try my Code for a change

Comment: Can you try alert($(".active", $(".btn-group")).length)

Comment: got the value using `$("#investadjust-debitcredit-button>.active").val()` but really i don't know how it worked, i think i would have been refereeing some old value. +1 for the post and marking as accepted. Jquery selector is valid, please remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use inputs, not buttons.

```
<div class="span3">
    <div>DEBIT/CREDIT</div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="investadjust-debitcredit-button">
        <input name="debitCredit" type="button" id="credit-button" class="btn active" value="CREDIT" />
        <input name="debitCredit" type="button" id="debi-button" class="btn" value="DEBIT" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should we need to change the button to input??

Comment: I thought that may be the problem if he's using VAR.value with a button.